# How to use nvidia-docker container as non-root user?

Tags: docker, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I want to use a CUDA container in Docker as a non root user, but am running into permission problems. Here's an example Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cudagl:11.2.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash testuser -G video,sudo

USER testuser
ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"
```

Running `nvidia-smi` gives the following error: `Failed to initialize NVML: Insufficient Permissions`

My application uses VirtualGL and Xvfb to render Chrome with a GPU if that's relevant. Works perfectly fine with the root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - Check the gid of `vglusers` group on the host. Add this group with the gid in the container, and add the user to this group.

So investigating this a bit, I looked at the nvidia devices in the container:

```
root@56cef279b83f:/# cd /dev
root@56cef279b83f:/dev# ls -l | grep nvidia
crw-rw---- 1 root 1005 195,   0 Nov 23 23:13 nvidia0
crw-rw---- 1 root 1005 195, 255 Nov 23 23:13 nvidiactl
crw-rw---- 1 root 1005 195, 254 Nov 23 23:13 nvidia-modeset
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 506,   0 Nov 23 23:13 nvidia-uvm
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 506,   1 Nov 23 23:13 nvidia-uvm-tools
```

The nvidia devices belonged to a group with gid 1005. This was odd as there was no group in the container with that ID.

I went to look into the devices on the host, and as per my VGL setup, they belong to `root`, or the `vglusers` group.

```
(venv) jsim@goliath:/var/log$ cd /dev/
(venv) jsim@goliath:/dev$ ls -l | grep nvidia
crw-rw----   1 root vglusers 195,   0 Nov 24 10:13 nvidia0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root           80 Nov 24 10:31 nvidia-caps
crw-rw----   1 root vglusers 195, 255 Nov 24 10:13 nvidiactl
crw-rw----   1 root vglusers 195, 254 Nov 24 10:13 nvidia-modeset
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root     506,   0 Nov 24 10:13 nvidia-uvm
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root     506,   1 Nov 24 10:13 nvidia-uvm-tools
```

As it turns out, `vglusers` has a gid of 1005!

```
jsim@goliath:/dev$ cat /etc/group | grep vglusers
vglusers:x:1005:jsim
```

So in my Dockerfile, all I had to do is add the group `vglusers` with gid 1005, and add my user to this group. Problem solved.

```
RUN groupadd -g 1005 vglusers && \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash testuser -u 1000 -g 1005 && \
    usermod -a -G video,sudo testuser
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it's not portable, you need to hardcode the GID into the RUN instruction. I've opened an issue over here for vscode's devcontainers extension that would partially solve this problem in that context: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7722 - If the issue gets enough up votes then the devs will look at it.